# How to put Volume/Network/Username icon to bottom panel in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, desktop

To better explain here's a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the applets (hit the handle on the left of the Notification Area, not any of the icons in it), uncheck `Lock to Panel`, and middle-drag them to the bottom panel. Lock again afterwards if you like.

Comment: Actually I accidentally deleted this. Is there a way to put it back on the bottom panel? The screenshot above is not really mine but just a sample, mine has no top panel anymore :-)

Comment: Right-click the panel and add them.

Comment: Yeah, thing is, there doesn't seem to be a volume adjuster/network manager/username option in the add panels menu